# Xelatex doesn't find any font

Tags: errors, xetex

I downloaded a `.cls` file from the internet, which contains a lot of templates for generating a fantasy-style document.

Requirement for generating the document is XeLaTeX, other than pdfLaTeX which I always used.

During compilation (either via console command or via TeXworks) I receive an error:

> The font "GaramondNo8" cannot be found.

Source is `\setmainfont{GaramondNo8}` from the downloaded `.cls` file. I changed the font to something like 'Times New Roman', but the error is always the same. No matter what font I define the compiler says that that font cannot be found.

What am I doing wrong? I'm using TexLive 2013 on a Windows machine.

### Edit

This is the `.cls` file (I reduced it to only contain the `\setmainfont` command. Error still occurs...)

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e} 
\ProvidesClass{dsa}[2014/02/06 v0.1]
\LoadClass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=2.1cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{7pt} 

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabu}
\setmainfont{GaramondNo8}
```

This is my `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{dsa}
\begin{document}
    \bfseries \Huge
    Die Rahjadan Kampagne

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: TeXLive 2013 is 'old' ;-) The main cause is often a wrong font name. Do you have the relevant fonts installed on your computer?

Comment: I have downloaded and installed the "nonfreefonts", which contain GaramondNo8. However, using "Times New Roman" doesn't work either.

I should note that i work under Windows.

Comment: i'm running `tlmgr update --all` now. Maybe it helps :-)

I didn't touch my TexLive installation for years. It was working and i followed the rule "Never touch a running system"

Comment: Can you add the link from where you downloaded this class file? And have you tried compiling a simple document that uses `fontspec` with a stadard class under XeLaTeX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fonts used in this example are obtained from:

1. [Heather Regular](http://www.1001freefonts.com/heather_regular.font)
2. [DS Fette Gotisch](http://www.1001fonts.com/ds-fette-gotisch-font.html)
3. [EB Garamond08-Regular](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/eb-garamond)

and, by changing some of the code, leads to the pictured fonts. The font(s) used should be saved in the same location as the document being worked on. Also use `XeLaTeX`

```
\documentclass[a4, 11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=2.1cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{7pt} 

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabu}
\setmainfont{Heather.ttf}


\begin{document}
    \bfseries \Huge
    Die Rahjadan Kampagne

    \vspace{5mm}
    \fontspec{EBGaramond08-Regular.ttf}{\bfseries \Huge Die Rahjadan Kampagne}

    \vspace{5mm}
    \fontspec{DSFetteGotisch.ttf}{\bfseries \Huge Die Rahjadan Kampagne}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That did it. I was trying to install the font in texlive. Simply installing any *.ttf font in windows enables the font for latex.

Comment: @AlexanderMills My practice is to save all fonts in a folder and when needed make a document specific folder with the fonts used and document produced. If the fonts will be used a lot then make it global to the machine and texlive (if available).