# XeLaTeX unable to find fonts after reinstall of MiKTeX

Tags: xetex, luatex, miktex, fontspec, windows

Dear problem solvers,

After reinstalling Windows on my computer and subsequently reinstalling MiKTeX 2.9, I've been unable to compile with XeLaTeX (PDFLaTeX does work). I had no problems before.

What I tried without results:

- running `fc-cache`: this is not a recognized command
- running `updmap.exe` (it seems to run)
- LuaLaTeX
- All user MiKTeX and single user MiKTeX install
- Two different locations for MiKTeX install (standard and `C:\MiKTeX 2.9`)
- Two different `.tex` editors (Texmaker and TeXworks)
- Running a piece of example code from an answer in ([Xelatex doesn't find any font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256962/xelatex-doesnt-find-any-font)): same errors, I've installed the fonts for all users, and put them in the same folder as the `.tex` file.

To me, it sounds like I made some installation error, but I don't know where to start finding a solution. I would be really appreciative with any pointers to fix this issue!

Also, the log file error message:
[image: Log file error message]

And the error messages in Texmaker:
[image: Error messages in Texmaker]

The code I'm running:

```latex
\documentclass[a4, 11pt]{scrartcl}



\usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=2.1cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{7pt} 

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabu}
\setmainfont{Heather.ttf}


\begin{document}
    \bfseries \Huge
    Die Rahjadan Kampagne

    \vspace{5mm}
    \fontspec{EBGaramond08-Regular.ttf}{\bfseries \Huge Die Rahjadan Kampagne}

    \vspace{5mm}
    \fontspec{DSFetteGotisch.ttf}{\bfseries \Huge Die Rahjadan Kampagne}

\end{document}
```

The link to the log file:
https://we.tl/t-ZhxPup4niF

The picture of my folder structure:
[image: folderstrucpicture]

Comment: The first error looks as if there is some error in the code. Check for updates as user and admin. If the problem show a small but complete example and its log file.

Comment: Dear Ulrike, thanks for your response. I've added the code. The log file and error message are generated by that piece of code. Or do you need an other log file?

Comment: I need another log-file, the one from your document. But at first run the update manager in user and admin mode. Btw: avoid the tabu package, it is broken and not maintained. And don't load xunicode, that it unneeded and deprecated.

Comment: I have added the, what I think is, the log file you need. I've run the update manager (in the MiKTeX console), but only as user. I have to reinstall to run it as an admin, which I will do now. 

Also, I will remove the packages and come back to you with the results. However, I don't think that this will yield any results, as the document was working before the reinstall.

Comment: You don't need to reinstall if you don't have a multiuser installation. Then update in user mode is enough.

Comment: OK, then I just did that, MiKTeX should be up to date.

Comment: Update: removing the packages did not solve the issue. Am I understanding correctly how to run the update manager? I'm hitting the "Check for updates" button in the MiKTeX console. Furthermore, I've refreshed the font map files. All to no avail.

Comment: Your miktex looks up-to-date and your first error is gone. Now you simply get a font not found error. Do you actually have `EBGaramond08-Regular.ttf`? Where is it?

Comment: True, my first error is gone. 

I've installed the fonts for all users. They are in the same folder as the .tex file. I've included the picture of my folder for completeness sake.

Comment: Show also the extensions of the fonts (it is a good idea to enable extensions anyway).

Comment: Done, I've added the new picture. The extensions are .otf

Comment: Well then you should correct your code `\fontspec{EBGaramond08-Regular.ttf}` is then wrong and it is no wonder that xetex can't find the font.

Comment: I feel pretty stupid now. This indeed fixes the issue. So, to solve this issue for my other document, I have to add all the fonts I'm using manually (Ariel, Ariel_Bold, etc.)? I'm still a bit puzzled that a reinstall caused this issue, and it just went right the first time. 

Anyhow, thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Just a note regarding missing `fc-cache.exe`: It is planned to be added, cf. [Create "fc-cache.exe" as alias](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/438) (MiKTeX repo on Github), but for now you have to use `miktex-fc-cache.exe`.