# EPS images not showing in Latex (and EPS-to-PDF conversion failing)

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, eps, ghostscript

A couple of days ago I posted an issue here (link: [XeLaTeX unable to find fonts after reinstall of MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526557/xelatex-unable-to-find-fonts-after-reinstall-of-miktex)), where I was suddenly unable to compile a document after reinstalling windows+tex software. I thought this was related to some fonts not being installed correctly. And indeed, fixing a stupid mistake resolved the issue in the example I provided. Also, refer to this question for all the actions I already tried.

However, my main document still does not compile. So, still there is some underlying issue which prevents me to compile the document (which worked flawlessly before!!).

What is happening/going wrong:

- My `.eps` are suddenly being converted to `pdf` files and placed in the folder. This puzzles me, because I think this was not even required before. This process also fails, leaving a blank `pdf` file. Viewing the file with an eps-viewer shows the image fine.
- Compiling my original file with `xelatex` is throwing the Ghostscript error shown in the image and does not output a pdf. It does compile with `lualatex`, but the document is not even looking close to what it used to look like.

  - My minimal example does not compile with `xelatex`
  - With `lualatex` it does compile, but two strange things are happening: the "s" in "Test" written with the DSFetteGotisch font is not showing. Furthermore, the image is not showing (the box is however).

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[a4, 11pt]{scrartcl}



\usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=2.1cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{7pt} 

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{makecell}
\setmainfont{Heather.ttf}


\begin{document}
    \bfseries \Huge
   Test

    \vspace{5mm}
    \fontspec{EBGaramond08-Regular.otf}{\bfseries \Huge Test}

    \vspace{5mm}
    \fontspec{DSFetteGotisch.ttf}{\bfseries \Huge Test}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \fbox{\includegraphics{Figs/Bode_MS.eps}}   
    % \includegraphics[width = 0.9 \textwidth]{Figs/Bode_MS.eps}
    \caption{TEST}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Link to the log file of the example: 
https://we.tl/t-EqfcOOzsmh

Main file error message:
[image: Ghostscript error]

Example pdf result:
[image: examplepdf]

Finally, I want to say: I am no expert at all with software. But I do think this is some crazy freak error (primary because the errors appeared after a reinstall). So maybe there might be some underlying setting in windows 10 or windows defender (or something like that) that might cause this.. I think the two errors (the Ghostscript and eps) I shared here are symptoms which might be resolved by a correct installation/setting of something.

The `eps` file: 
https://we.tl/t-37W0MySYmZ

Comment: Don't mix all your problems in one question. Try to solve them one by one. That with lualatex the eps is converted to a pdf is normal, that the graphic doesn't show up indicates (as the ghostscript error about an invalid font)  a problem with this special eps. So you should make it available for inspection. Your font problem is unrelated to this, so open a new question for it.

Comment: I don't think I am mixing problems. I think that these are all symptoms of a single problem. 

I did the obvious thing, and tried the compile my files on another computer. It worked fine. This further enforces my belief that this is not a "coding" or a "file" based error, but an installation/settings error. Anyway, I added the ```eps``` file.

Comment: Please also specify the version of ghostscript being used as a rencet version is known to have errors.

Comment: I manually downloaded and installed Ghostscript 9.50. Not sure if this was necessary, as this was not required before the reinstall. In my MiKTeX console it specifies that the package is packaged on 15-12-2019, which should also be version 9.50, but I don't see any mention of a version.

Comment: I'm running GPL Ghostscript 9.26 on my linux box with a 100% up to date TeXLive 2019, no issues running xelatex with this eps after I outcommented the font lines as I do not have those fonts.

Comment: You are mixing problems. I can't help you with your eps, it works fine here.  Try to convert it to pdf externally, e.g. with ghostscript. Regarding your font, with lualatex you can try `\fontspec{DSFetteGotisch.ttf}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]`. This requires a current, up-to-date tex system and that you compile with `lualatex-dev` instead of `lualatex`.

Comment: Also interesting that you system is using on the file conversion of the eps, mine does not.

Comment: I was wrong regarding the font: harf mode won't help. it is simply missing the s.

Comment: I have reverted to an old version of Ghostscript. Both my main file and the example are compiling now! Except the "S", but I guess that is indeed simply missing..

Comment: there seem to be something wrong with miktex and ghostscript. In another thread a ghostscript problem was solved by installing a full miktex. And here is a long thread about the fontmap handling of miktex: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/393